# How to downgrade Angular version in latest Jhipster?

Tags: angular, jhipster

Jhipster does not ask the Angular version while creating project, it automatically uses angular 9. How can I change it to Angular 8 as it is my project requirement.

Comment: How can it be a requirement to use v8? You should really consider using the latest version to ensure you are up to date with the latest security fixes. You will have to upgrade in future anyway as LTS only runs for 18 months for each version.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but if you must then the easiest way is to use an older version of JHipster. Angular 9 was introduced in version [6.8.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2020/03/08/jhipster-release-6.8.0.html) so you could use the one before ([6.7.1](https://www.jhipster.tech/2020/02/12/jhipster-release-6.7.1.html)).

First remove the latest JHipster (`6.8.0`) from your machine

```
npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
```

Then install the version you want, in this case `6.7.1`

```
npm i -g generator-jhipster@6.7.1
```

And [generate](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/) your project normally.

I think this is the easiest way since you could in theory use the latest version and downgrade angular manually but I doubt it would be easy (the generated code expects to be using Angular 9).